# Yammer Embed X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN in Chrome

Tags: yammer

When I visit a page on my website with a yammer embed with a network that is different than the network my browser is logged into I get a `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` error and the embed iframe fails to load.  When I pull up the URL that the `iframe` was trying to load it is prompting me to join the external yammer network and does, indeed have a response header of `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` on it.

Is there a way to detect this situation and prompt the user to join the network (or even just to log out so *something* shows in the embed iframe?

Comment: same issue here and that really depends on browsers and OS's Safari on IPhone 6+ has that issue too.